# Linux script shows unnecessary files

Tags: linux, unix, cron

I have written following script and it shows some unnecessary files when i'm running it. I just want to execute only the command and receive the alerts only.
the script as follows

```
 df -h | nawk '/backup/ {print $5 " "  $6}' | while read line;
  do
        usep=$(echo  $line | nawk  '{printf "%d", $1}' )    
        partition=$(echo $line | nawk '{print $2}')
        if (( $usep >= 90)); then
                 echo "$partition ($usep%)" | mailx -s "172.27.68.101" 0234343456@alert.abc.lk;
                echo  "$partition ($usep%)" | mailx -s "172.27.68.101" amalw@abc.lk;
        echo  "$partition ($usep%)" | mailx -s "172.27.68.101" amalw@abc.lk;
        fi
  done
```

Follwing image shows the output problem

[image]

How can i add multiple recipient to this script without opening such directories?

Comment: Did you try adding you script in a bash file and execute it?

Comment: actually i want to put this in to a script and execute as a cronjob. Before enter into the script i tried it directly as i posted the question. since i'm new to Linux i don't understand why it s opening this directory when i'm adding more echo lines

Answer (score 3):

To paste a multi-line bash code into terminal, add parenthesis around the lines otherwise each line gets run as a separate command as soon as it gets pasted:

```
(df -h | nawk '/backup/ {print $5 " "  $6}' | while read line; do
    usep=$(echo  "$line" | nawk  '{printf "%d", $1}')
    partition=$(echo $line | nawk '{print $2}')
    if(("$usep" >= 90)) ; then echo "$partition ($usep%)" | mailx -s "172.27.68.101" 0234343456@alert.abc.lk;
        echo  "$partition ($usep%)" | mailx -s "172.27.68.101" amalw@abc.lk;
        echo  "$partition ($usep%)" | mailx -s "172.27.68.101" amalw@abc.lk;
    fi
done)
```

Comment: Thanx. But i'm stil having the same issue.

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the result by adding  parenthesis around the lines?

Comment: This method is perfectly works. i made a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly command  `df -h|grep backup|sed 's/\%//g'|awk '$5 >= 90 {print $5"% "$6}'` for having FS(*Partition*) more than 90% usage. 
 the rest of command to alert trought mail. Then :

`df -h|grep backup|sed 's/\%//g'|awk '$5 >= 90 {print $5"% "$6}'|while read USAGE PARTITION
do
echo "$PARTITION ($USAGE)"|mailx -s "172.27.68.101" "0234343456@alert.abc.lk,amalw@abc.lk"
done`

Comment: You should explain you answer in more depth? Also- how is this any different / better than the prior answer?

Comment: Hello @DerekBrown

Comment: Hello @DerekBrown firstly `df -h|grep backup|sed 's/\%//g'|awk '$5 >= 90 {print $5"% "$6}'`  for having FS more than 90% usage. the rest of command to alert trought mail.

Comment: to clarify: could you revise your answer to include that?